# Pasting text to terminal

Tags: bash, perl

I have this small function:

```
writecmd () {
  perl -e 'ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, $_ for split //, do{ chomp($_ = <>); $_ }' ;
}
```

It prints the text I give it to the STDOUT, and prints it also to the command line buffer.

For example:

```
[root]$ echo "text" | perl -e 'ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, $_ for split //, do{ chomp($_ = <>); $_ }' ;
text[root]$ text
```

How can I make it not output the text to STDOUT but only to the cli buffer?

Or more specifically, I use it to print a variable, and after that I use `read` to allow users to change that variable while editing it in place instead of writing it all over again.

Thanks.

Comment: See also [Can bash write to its own input stream?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213799/45537)

Comment: @HåkonHægland That's awesome thanks. But I didn't understand from it how to eliminate the first output of the string.

Comment: @HåkonHægland the bash option is also not good because it displays a warning:  `bind: warning: line editing not enabled`

Comment: I know this is really old, but the output IS NOT being sent to stdout, it is being "typed" to the terminal before the prompt is displayed, then re-displayed by bash (specifically readline).
Wrap the perl command with `stty -echo; <magic>; stty echo` and it behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the output to the terminal is somehow related to whether the prompt has returned or not when `ìoctl` is executed. For example, the following works as expected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork();
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    sleep 1;
    my $cmd = "ls";
    # 0x5412 = TIOCSTI, see c include file: <asm-generic/ioctls.h>
    ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, $_ for split //, $cmd;
}
```

If I remove the `sleep 1`, it does not work ( since then there is not enough time for the prompt to return ).